# Angular - Showing a different page (simple)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm doing an app and my app.html works great until I don't want that template. For example, for the login page I want a full page, without sidebar,navbar,etc...

ATM is showing my navbar and stuff with the login page in the middle, I dont want that

How do I make this work?

App Module

```
    const appRoutes:Routes = [
  {path: '', component:LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component:EnvironmentComponent},
  {path: 'docker', component:DockerComponent}
];
```

app.html

```
<html>
  <app-nav></app-nav>
  <body>
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <div class="container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </body>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this : https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-hide-navbar-login-page

Comment: can anyone help me??

Comment: just use this in the **app.html**

`<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
and create dashboard component page and use your sidebar,footer there
example: **dashboard.component.html**
`<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <div class="container">
      //your other components here
    </div>
<app-footer></app-footer>`
And in the app-routing.module.ts
add 
`{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }`
Hope it will help to your need